# Best way to convert ticks to minuts in Java (finance)

Tags: java, date, finance

I've got a huge data base that contain for each day a text file with the following format : 
"HH:mm:ss xxxx.xx"
for almost each second of each trading day, so I have thousands lines in each text's file. 
I'm looking for the best way to convert these lines into a HashMap where each key represents a new minute of the trading day.

For example I'd like to make theses few lines :

```
00:08:48    9819,9
00:09:10    9818,7
00:09:44    9819,9
00:09:51    9820,9
00:10:07    9822,1
```

looks like this in the HashMap :

```
myHashMap.put("00:09:00", 9818.7)

myHashMap.put("00:10:00", 9822.1)
```

PS : I know "00:09:00" is not a good Date format, it's just for the example !

Comment: Sounds more like a job of an SQL database afterwards you could create an SELECT QUERY using with grouping. Anyway when you use Java note that HashMap will not store multiple entries with the same key.

Comment: If you think you may do something more than snapshotting the first tick in each minute, you could consider getting a simple example going using Esper.  This is their doc on CSV sources http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esperio-reference/html/adapter_file.html

You can then do more advanced operators in a streaming SQL like syntax.  
`select first(*), last(*) from SensorEvent.win:time(10 sec)`

But its probably overkill if there is no chance you want anything more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) -  [`Files#lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) does a great job at that. The [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day.

WARNING : a [**OutOfMemoryError**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) could be thrown if too much objects were to be created in memory.

```
Map<LocalTime, Double> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\data.txt"))
                                  .map(x -> x.split(" "))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                               x -> LocalTime.parse(x[0]), 
                                               x -> Double.valueOf(x[1])));
```

---

For a specific `double` format, you may use the following

```
(Double)NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(x[1]))
```

---

### Monetary

Since the data seems to be monetary, `BigDecimal` may be a better choice instead of a `Double`.

```
Map<LocalTime, BigDecimal> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\data.txt"))
                                  .map(x -> x.split(" "))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                               x -> LocalTime.parse(x[0]), 
                                               x -> new BigDecimal(x[1])));
```

Comment: This could be made more efficient by splitting the string first and then making the map. ie. `.map(line -> line.split(" "))` after `.lines(...)`.

Comment: Also, given that the data there is using commas as decimal places, (Double)NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(x[1])) might be better for the value in the map.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I would replace `Double` with [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for accuracy since the values apparently are monetary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been really helpful !